# AutoSelectCertificateForUrls is not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome, registry

I have a domain and a client certificate for that domain, which is required if a user wants to visit certain pages like admin login page etc. So far so good, my cert authentication is working correctly.

The problem is that every time a client tries to visit these pages, Google Chrome popup shows up asking for certificate selection. I need to use Google Chrome, otherwise Firefox would be a perfect alternative since it has a "remember my choice"-like tick box on the same dialog. Google Chrome does not offer the same "remember" functionality.

I tried with the following .reg file and although I can see that Google Chrome "sees" the Policy, the Policy isn't applied (popup still shows up).

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"='{"pattern":"https://[*.]domain.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"ISSUER_NAME"}}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be late but the following steps helped similar issues I faced:

1. Visit `chrome://policy`.
2. Check that `status` column for `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` policy. If it shows an error, navigate to `Show more` link.

In my case, the policy value had `Schema vaidation error at ...` warnings and indicated that there were two problems:

1. A quote in name of the Certificate's Issuer was causing the JSON to be invalid in the policy's value. To fix this, I escaped the strings using backslash:

```
\"SUBJECT\": \"Issuer O'Toole\".
```

- Note: while using automation tools such as Wix Toolset, escaping backslashes didn't work; so HTML codes had to be used: `&quot;`.

2. The filter section of JSON uses capitalized keys: `SUBJECT`, `ISSUER`, etc. This is not a problem in your example above. But I was using `Subject`, and `Issuer` which were generating errors.